# Sending an image path in json response with paperclip in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, paperclip, rails-api

I am using paperclip for images in rails api.My problem is to send all ads which have also avatars along with other attributes.

I cant understand how I send all ads along with their images.

My response is like that

```
def ads_list
        @ads = Ad.all.limit(10)
        render json: {:success=>true, :message=>"List of all Ads",:ads=>@ads}, :status=>200
end
```

Through this all data send except avatars_urls.How I send avatar along with this?

My search till now.I found a solution for only one single object like this

Add in your model

```
def avatar_url
    avatar.url(:medium)
end
```

and response is like that

```
render :json => @model.to_json(:only => [:id,:name,:homephone,:cellphone], :methods => [:avatar_url])
```

How I customize it for all objects or any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it

```
render json: {:success=>true, :message=>"List of all Ads",:ads=>@ads.map {|u| u.attributes.merge(:thumbnail_url => u.thumbnail.url)}}, :status=>200
```